# Getting a distance from Google maps and multiplying it by one of two rates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I found this code online that almost does what I need it to. The problem is that I need it to give me a price based on whether the user wants Same Day Delivery or Same Day Urgent Delivery. I can't get it to work though.

The form should take two addresses, calculate the distance between them and multiply them by £1 if Same Day has been chosen or £1.20 if Same Day Urgent has been chosen.

```
<?php
session_start();
$rate = 1;
$urgent = 1.2;
//}

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
      var map = null;
      var directionDisplay;
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

      function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        var UK = new google.maps.LatLng(55.7591402,-4.1883331);

        var mapOptions = {  
                    center              : UK,
                    zoom                : 4,
                    minZoom             : 3,
                    streetViewControl   : false,
                    mapTypeId           : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    zoomControlOptions  : {style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.MEDIUM}
                };


        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

         //Find From location    
    var fromText = document.getElementById('start');
    var fromAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(fromText);
    fromAuto.bindTo('bounds', map);
    //Find To location
    var toText = document.getElementById('end');
    var toAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(toText);
    toAuto.bindTo('bounds', map);
    //  
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));

        /*var control = document.getElementById('control');
        control.style.display = 'block';
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP].push(control);*/
      }

      function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
        var request = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            computeTotalDistance(response);
          }
        });
      }
      function computeTotalDistance(result) {
      var total = 0;
      var myroute = result.routes[0];
      for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
      }
      total = total / 1000;
      /*Start Calculating Distance Fair*/
      if (document.getElementById('sameday').checked == true) {
          var cost = ((total * <?php echo $rate; ?>));
      }
      else if (document.getElementById('samedayurgent').checked == true) {
          var cost = ((total * <?php echo $urgent; ?>));
      }

            var fare = total * cost;
            var fare = Math.round(fare*100)/100;
      /*Distance Fair Calculation Ends*/

      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total Distance = " + total + " km and FARE = £" + fare;
      }

    function auto() {
    var input = document.getElementById[('start'), ('end')];
    var types
    var options = {
       types: [],
       componentRestrictions: {country: ["UK"]}
        };
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
     }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="initialize()">
<table width="380px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:5px;">
    <table width="375px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td><div id="map_canvas" style="width: 374px; height: 300px; border: solid 1px #336699"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div id="form" style="width:374px; text-align:center; border: solid 1px #336699; background:#d1e1e4;">
          <input type="radio" name="post-type" value="sameday" checked> Same Day
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="post-type" value="samedayurgent"> Same Day Urgent
            <br>
              From:
                <input type="text" id="start" size="60px" name="start" placeholder="Enter Location From">
                <br />
                To:
                <input size="60px" type="text" id="end" name="end" placeholder="Enter Destination ">
                <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calcRoute();">
             <div id="total"></div>
             </div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **I can't get it to works** is not a clear description of the problem. What does the code do now? What do you want it to do? I can see you are calculating `cost = total * rate` then `fare = total * cost` - which means `fare = total * total * cost` - which looks wrong

Comment: this is also a php page, where the `<?php` tag at the top isn't closed before html is being output - so that wont work very well either

Comment: Also, you didn't give your radio inputs for 'sameday' and 'samedayurgent' ids, so the statements `document.getElementById('sameday').checked == true` and `document.getElementById('samedayurgent').checked == true` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

based on what you said - get rid of

```
<?php
session_start();
$rate = 1;
$urgent = 1.2;
```

and change the computeTotalDistance function to

```
function computeTotalDistance(result) {
    var rate = 1;
    var urgent = 1.2;
    var total = 0;
    var cost;
    var myroute = result.routes[0];
    for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    }
    total = total / 1000;
    /*Start Calculating Distance Fair*/
    if (document.getElementById('sameday').checked == true) {
        cost = total * rate;
    } else if (document.getElementById('samedayurgent').checked == true) {
        cost = total * urgent;
    }
    cost = Math.round(cost * 100) / 100;
    /*Distance Fair Calculation Ends*/
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total Distance = " + total + " km and FARE = £" + cost;
}
```

and as Markai pointed out

```
<input type="radio" name="post-type" id='sameday' checked> Same Day
<br>
<input type="radio" name="post-type" id='samedayurgent'> Same Day Urgent
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I eventually got it to work on my own.

Comment: No sorry it's not that your changes to the function never worked. I never got to try it because I managed to work it out on my own in a different way.

I do appreciate your time, thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for everyone's help. Here's how I got it to work:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  var map = null;
       var directionDisplay;
       var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

   function initialize() {
   directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

   var UK = new google.maps.LatLng(56.9630794,-4.016831);

    var mapOptions = {  
        center              : UK,
                    zoom                : 6,
                    minZoom             : 3,
                    streetViewControl   : false,
                    mapTypeId           : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    zoomControlOptions  :     {style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.MEDIUM}
            };


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);

     //Find From location    
var fromText = document.getElementById('start');
var fromAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(fromText);
fromAuto.bindTo('bounds', map);
//Find To location
var toText = document.getElementById('end');
var toAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(toText);
toAuto.bindTo('bounds', map);
//  
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));

    /*var control = document.getElementById('control');
        control.style.display = 'block';
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP].push(control);*/
      }

      function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
        var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        computeTotalDistance(response);
      }
    });
  }
  function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  var total = 0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
  }
  total = total / 1609.344;
  var total = Math.round(total);
  /*Start Calculating Distance Fair*/

  var sameday = document.getElementById("sameday");
  var samedayurgent = document.getElementById("samedayurgent");

 if (sameday.checked)
 {
     var rate = 1;
 }
  else if (samedayurgent.checked)
 {
    var rate = 1.20;
 }              
    var fare = total * rate;
var fare = Math.round(fare*100)/100;

 if (fare < 5.5)
 {
    fare= 5.5;
 }

    var price = fare.toFixed(2)
  /*Distance Fair Calculation Ends*/

  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML =  " " + total + " miles";
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = " £" + price + " (excl. VAT)";
  }

function auto() {
var input = document.getElementById[('start'), ('end')];
var types
var options = {
   types: [],
   componentRestrictions: {country: ["UK"]}
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
 }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```